# only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views, I have tried moving to UI thread but nothing seems to work

Tags: java, android

I have looked through multiple threads trying to solve this already but this always hits the catch on the " mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);" line.

```
public void populateListView() // adds each string from json file to the listview of puzzles
{
    try {
        String[] strings = mPuzzleNames.toArray(new String[mPuzzleNames.size()]);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, strings);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //updates UI
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What invokes `populateListView()`? How have you moved this to the UI thread?

Comment: populateListView() is called in an AsyncTask, so I believe that's on a background thread.

 And I tried putting

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


     @Override


     public void run() {


       //stuff that updates ui


    }
});`   (sorry about all the edits I can't figure out this formatting for the life of me)

Comment: Is it called from `doInBackground()` in the `AsyncTask`? If so, that would be in the background. What happens with `runOnUiThread` when you tried it? Can you share that code?

Comment: I needed to use a handler it appears, the guy below solved it. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Handler:

```
public void populateListView() {
    try {
        String[] strings = mPuzzleNames.toArray(new String[mPuzzleNames.size()]);

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, strings);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also there is no need to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as you are actually recreating adapter every time.